# Session Management with Spring boot + REST using simple Map

Tags: java, spring, rest, session, spring-boot

I am developing the backend of an Angular + REST APIs application, the application needs some sort of session management (user is authenticated first using OTP then I need to keep track of any of his subsequent requests) ... I saw two examples for managing session with REST , first is using [JWT + OAuth2](https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50) which I think is somehow over engineered as OAuth2 is not designed as I understand to be used within the same application (resource and authorization server are both within the same application) ... the [other example uses redis](http://www.sedooe.com/2016/04/rest-authentication-using-spring-security-and-spring-session/)  and I can't introduce it to my current application ... actually what I need is something simple as storing the session in a static map-like structure that I always refer to (and moreover it would be nice to update the token with every client call to the backend, same like OAuth2 but simpler) ... I also checked the spring boot dependencies concerning sessions, all I found name external resource to be included like

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-hazelcast</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

And I have a restriction not to add any external caching dependency like hazelcast ... also for a jdbc-session management, it will really affect performance to go to database with every client call

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security

Comment: It's good but it doesn't address spring boot directly, I will make a look and try to tune, thank you

Comment: @osama yaccoub Did u sort out the issue ? Can u post the solution in here. ? I also ruin with one.thanks.

Comment: How did you solved this?